# Set style to mat-dialog-container

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

Im trying to edit the mat-dialog-container but Im not able to, I tried with :host::ng-deep and also I look for answers of this and I found that I should be ablo to give it style by adding a class, but the style is not changin, here is the code about what I found

for the style.css file

```
.custom-dialog-container .mat-dialog-container {
overflow-y: hidden !important;
display: flex !important;
background-color: red;
}
```

For the ts componen

```
  abrirForm(id:number){
const data = id??null
this.ventana.open(ModalInspeccionComponent,{data:data, disableClose:true,maxWidth: '100vw', panelClass: 'custom-dialog-container'}).afterClosed().subscribe(e =>{
  if (e) {
    console.log(e);        
  }
})
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog opens outside of the component, so styles in the component file will not be applied to it. Place your styles for `.custom-dialog-container` in your root css/scss file, and they should apply to the dialog then.

Here is a minimal example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ggzfwu?file=src/styles.css

Comment: Yes, I already did that, I set them in Style.css that is the main css file, still not working

Comment: Does it work if you remove `.mat-dialog-container` from the style declaration? e.g., `.custom-dialog-container { //... styles here }`

Comment: No, it also doesnt work, but I did it, I made it by setting style in the ts file by using document.getElementById(), have no idea why it dindt work to me, because it seems to be the answer

Comment: I would not recommend that approach. Setting styles from TS simply is not necessary for this use case. Please refer to the example I updated my answer with, perhaps it will get you where you need to be.

Comment: I made it work with you answer, it was that I have an error with my style files and that the element that I wanted to edit was autogenerated inside the mat dialog, thanks